# Retrofit runtime error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I am having errors with my retrofit code. I guess I am missing something or not understanding something(Considering I've started coding in retrofit today and in android about a week back.) Here is my full error(in android studio at runtime.):

```html
08-04 09:24:11.230  16349-16349/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.apurva.myapplication, PID: 16349
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apurva.myapplication/com.example.apurva.myapplication.MainActivity}: retrofit.RetrofitError
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at $Proxy0.me(Native Method)
            at com.example.apurva.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:266)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:240)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextUnconnected(RouteSelector.java:156)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:130)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:312)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:235)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:262)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:219)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:192)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
            at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at $Proxy0.me(Native Method)
            at com.example.apurva.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The files in my android project:

**MainActivity.java**

```html
package com.example.apurva.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UserService userService;
        String token = "A";
        userService = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class, UserService.BASE_URL, token);
        User user = userService.me();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**ServiceGenerator.java**

```html
package com.example.apurva.myapplication;


import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.client.OkClient;

/**
 * Created by apurva on 4/8/15.
 */
public class ServiceGenerator {
    private ServiceGenerator() {
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl, final String token) {
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(baseUrl)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

        if (token != null) {
            builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", token);
                }
            });
        }

        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```html
package com.example.apurva.myapplication;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.client.OkClient;
import retrofit.http.POST;

/**
 * Created by apurva on 4/8/15.
 */
public interface UserService {

        public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/auth";

        @POST("/convert-token")
        User me();

}
```

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated the error is a runtime and I'm having no issues while gradle building or running the application. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception which you get is self-explanatory: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I.e. your code makes network calls in the main thread. The exception is also says where exactly it happens: in the 19 line of code of `MainActivity`:

```
User user = userService.me();
```

If you read [Retrofit documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) you have to know that when you call methods of your service `Retrofit` will make it synchronously, i.e. at the same thread, and in your case this is main thread.

To make calls asynchronously you need to pass `Callback`:

```
@POST("/convert-token")
void me(Callback<User> cb);
```

`PS` I would highly recommend you to read about `Java` firstly because basically you didn't recognize the place of error and this is basic skill of software development in general.